# work on Samsung but blank screen on Nexus 7

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Happy New Year,

I am developing my application by following [This tutorial](http://steigert.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/1-libgdx-tutorial-introduction.html) (using LibGdx, extents Game, with AbstractScreen, using Stage). However, currently I am experiencing a very funny issue. Everything display correct on my Samsung phone but not on my ASUS Nexus 7. Please see [this link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3pX6b4ed2DoWW1BVDB3QXJpQ3c/edit) for the recorded video (MP4: ~800kb) of both devices. As you can see from the Samsung phone, you can see the “Fullmoon Inc.” splash screen (~25 secs). However, my nexus 7 display nothing at all even though I am sure that my application is running on my nexus 7 (sound played on certain timeframe). I tried to update my nexus 7, reset back to factory default, run on empty profile, still no luck at all. I am absolutely no idea what to do to fix it.

Another thing is that the loading bar on the loading screen (from 5secs – 23secs) is not display correctly. According to the following code, the loading bar (the yellow windows) should load in a smooth manner. However, as per what you can see on the video, it is not. Currently the bar only display "After" everything is loaded. Can anyone please lead me back to the correct path?

```
loadingPercent = Interpolation.linear.apply(loadingPercent, thisApps.assetManager.getProgress(), 0.1f);
this.loadingYellowBox.setWidth(-1040 + (int) (loadingPercent * 1040));
```

Thank you very much, and all comments are welcome.

Comment: Without more code we cannot really help you. Nexus 7 had another screen resolution, probably also aspect ratio. Maybe that's why it is black? No assets found for this device maybe? Does it run on desktop?

Comment: Thanks @noone, yes. it does run on Desktop. the funniest part is that Nexus does run the loading screen but not any other screen after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally figured out where the problem came from. the issue is that when i pack all my images, i set the `Max page width` and `Max page height` to 4086. i am guessing that somehow Nexus did not "really" load those images. problem solved when i reduced both `Max page width` and `Max page height` to 2048. anyway, i still appreciated helps from both @noone and @son-of-the-northern-darkness

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the second part of question. AssetManager calculates percent based om number of asssets not on their size. Suppose you have huge texture atlas which is packed in one texture and several other small resources. Loading of the atlas takes 9 seconds and there are 4 other small resource which take 1 second to load.

So, see what happens. You have 20%-20%-20%-20%-20% when you expect 90%-10&.
If you want to more precise percentage you need to calculate percentage some other way.

Blank screen glitch is trickier. You need to check that Stage is properly initialized, aspect ratio is correct, resources are loaded correctly. You can download source code for libgdx, add it to your project and go through render method with debugger. If you find something suspicious there you can update this post or create a new one.

Comment: Thanks buddy, your explanation does make sense. I use TexturePacker to pack all my graphic files (TexturePacker created 3 PNG, and 1 pack file).  Currently, all I need to do is load the pack file, which resulting loading bar jumping from 0% to 100% since it is only loading 1 resource. It seems that it is not an optimal way to display the loading percentage. Looks like I will need to split it to multiple files. Once again, thank you very much, @son-of-the-northern-darkness.